# How to manage Type declaration for two different but related projects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have two projects for my front end, JS objects from Project 1 are being used in Project two.

Currently I have written all the types and methods available in Project 1 into index.d.ts of project 2.

But now if I change a method signature in project 1 and update it to Interface.
How to update same in the index.d.ts of project 2

I use Visual Studio Code, and Single work space for both the projects

Answer (score 0):

The best answer in this situation is to create a third project which contains the objects used by both project 1 and project 2 and to build this project as a JS module which can be npm installed into project 1 and project 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a private npm package containing all you type definitions and models, and then install it in the appropriate project.

**This is a helpful link:**

“How to make a beautiful, tiny npm package and publish it” by Jonathan Wood https://link.medium.com/8EU8gTGbAW